# ItemPresenter messes with PathGeometry absolute position inside ItemTemplate with a Canvas ItemPanel

Tags: wpf, canvas, itemscontrol, pathgeometry

I have an `ItemsControl` with a `Canvas` as its `ItemsPanel` and `Path` as the `ItemTemplate`. The goal is to plot a graph, so the `Path.Data` should contain a geometry to be drawn in the Canvas with absolute coordinates.

If I instantiate a Canvas and put the path directly inside it, it works fine.

But if I use an ItemsControl, every Path ends up wrapped inside a ContentPresenter, and then the coordinates are lost, since the ContentPresenter aligns to Canvas origin.

Here is my code:

```
        <ItemsControl
            ItemsSource="{Binding Signals}"
        >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path 
                        Stroke="Red"
                        StrokeThickness="1" 
                        StrokeDashCap="Round" 
                        StrokeLineJoin="Round" 
                        Stretch="Fill" 
                        Data={Binding Converter=SignalToGeometryConverter}
                    />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Try removing `Stretch="Fill"` from your `Path`

Comment: It also works for me if I restore Stretch="Fill" and prefix all path geometry strings with `"M 0,0"` -- followed by `"M x,y"` for whatever `x,y` where I actually want the path to start. If I `"M -100,-100"` and stretch, it offsets everything to bring `-100,-100` into view. Every time I use the `Stretch` attribute on `Path`, I end up knowing less than I did beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to be using a `Canvas` for the `ItemsPanel` in that `ItemsControl`, *and* you really need to fill the parent, you may be in a tough spot. If you can get by with a `Grid` for the `ItemsPanel`, you're all set.

What's getting you here isn't the `ContentPresenter`, it's the `Stretch`. That's causing the `Path` to fill its parent -- but not in the way you think. `"M 100,100 L 200,200"`, with any `Stretch` other than `None`, will draw a line starting at the upper left corner of the parent. The bounding box it's going to use is the maximum and minimum x and y values the path geometry actually uses. It assumes you only care about areas where you bothered to go. If you're superimposing multiple paths which have different upper left (*and lower right*) bounds, they'll all be scaled and offset differently, making a total hash of everything.

When you think about it, even if the stretching did start at 0,0 regardless, how would it know what to use for lower right bounds? The paths don't know about each other. If you had one Path, and added each of your current things to it as a different figure, that would be one thing. But this way, there's no common frame of reference that they're aware of.

So the quickest fix is to remove `Stretch="Fill"`, but then nothing will stretch. And as long as you're using `Canvas` for an `ItemsPanel`, you may as well not try to stretch the paths, because (as far as I can tell by testing) they won't stretch anyhow in that case.

If you do want to stretch, first you need to all of your paths to have the same bounding box, whether or not they actually use the whole thing. That means first calculating how much horizontal and vertical space you're going to need, and prefixing each path data with

```
M 0,0 M xmax,ymax
```

...before moving to the *actual* point you want to start the `Path` at.

And then change your `Canvas` to a `Grid`.

Here's the code I tested with:

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Signals, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
        >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Path 
                    Stroke="DeepSkyBlue" 
                    StrokeThickness="1"
                    Data="{Binding}"
                    Stretch="Fill"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int left = 10;
        int top = 100;
        int bottom = 200;

        var signals = 
            Enumerable.Range(0, 19)
            .Select(n => $"M 0,0 M 300,300 M {(n * 10) + left},{top} L {(n * 15) + left},{bottom}")
            .ToList();

        //  Show shared bounding box
        signals.Add("M 0,0 L 300,0 L 300,300 L 0,300 Z");

        Signals = signals;
    }

    public IList Signals
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(SignalsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SignalsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SignalsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Signals", typeof(IList), typeof(MainWindow),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your thorough answer! Actually I didn't have the intention to stretch-fill anything - the Fill value was a leftover from earlier design attempts. It should have been removed long ago, I only forgot, and it was somewhat hidden in the verbosity of everything.
Just removing that made everything work, but anyway your further elaborations have been enlightening! Thanks again!

Comment: @heltonbiker You're welcome. It was a fun question. I learned a lot myself!

Comment: As a side note, I have been fairly involved with "graph plotting" using WPF. I am getting best results by providing geometries with global transforms to the shapes I draw, and usually those shapes are of `Path` type, with various types of geometry (RectangleGeometry, PathGeometry, etc.). That way I can apply something like a "ViewPort" to the canvas, and obtain nice zooming effects just by changing the (databound) Transform.

Comment: That creates a nice independence between "model" coordinates (x = time, y = intensity, in my application domain) and "view" coordinates (pixels), so that zooming can be a view-only activity, MVVM-wise, performed by event-handlers in code-behind.

Comment: @heltonbiker I love transforms. I was assuming you had data coming in from somewhere, and wanted to treat it as opaque: Just put it were it says it is. But of course if you set the bounding area explicitly as I have it, then you've got to paw through the numbers anyway. Not the best thought out solution ever. Probably just as well you don't need to stretch.